# Are there better ways to approach these Python loops?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working through a scraping preparation function where pages of results lead to product pages.  The function has a default maximum number of results pages, or pages per set of results, to crawl to prevent a simple mistake.

Here's what I have so far.  Does the way I'm implementing the maximums with the for loops make sense?  Is there a more "pythonic" way? I'm coming at this from a completely learning perspective. Thanks.

```
def my_crawler(url, max_pages = 1, max_items = 1):

    for page_number in range(1, max_pages + 1):
        url = url + str(page_number)
        source_code = requests.get(url).text

        products = SoupStrainer(class_ = 'productTags')
        soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code, 'html.parser', parse_only=products)

        for item_number, a in enumerate(soup.find_all('a')):
            print(str(item_number) + ': ' + a['href'])

            if item_number == max_items - 1: break

my_crawler('http://www.thesite.com/productResults.aspx?&No=')
```

Comment: You should consider using string formatting on `url` instead of just appending the number.

Comment: Your question is much more suitable for [codereview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)(considering your code actually works).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `for` loop is fine, but

```
def my_crawler(url, max_pages = 1, max_items = 1):
    for page_number in range(1, max_pages + 1):
        url = url + str(page_number)
         ^
         |
```

You have changed the `url` parameter; the next time through the loop this will not work properly (you will seek page 1, page 12, page 123...)

Try instead

```
    source_code = requests.get(url + str(page_number)).text
```

This makes a temporary string without changing `url`.